# How can I add a UTCTime to a UTCDate?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime

for example:

```
"Tue May 25 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200"
   +            "14:15:00"
__________________________________
"Tue May 25 2021 14:15:00 GMT+0200"
```

How can I add these two values in JS or in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
let str1 = "Tue May 25 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200";
let str2 = "14:15:00";

let dt = new Date(str1);
let [h,m,s] = str2.split(":");

dt.setSeconds(dt.getSeconds() + h*3600 + m*60 + s*1);
```

Comment: The OP wants to add the time, not set the time, so `dt.setSeconds(dt.getSeconds() + h*3600 + m*60 + s*1)` where multiplication will convert the strings to numbers. ;-)

Comment: Excellent catch.